# How to show message notifications when the user is out of the app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

I am using firebase there I can see when a new "Child" is added, I need to show a notification when a new child is added
I am using this code but it does not work

(The notifications work but just shows in a activity, i need to show the notification when user is out of the app, like facebook or whatsapp

Method:

```
public Notification createNotification(boolean makeHeadsUpNotification) {
    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings_real_black_24dp)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentTitle("Sample Notification")
            .setContentText("This is a normal notification.");


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);
        }

    if (makeHeadsUpNotification) {
        Intent push = new Intent();
        push.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        push.setClass(this, UserActivity.class);

        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                push, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder
                .setContentText("Heads-Up Notification on Android L or above.")
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);
    }
    return notificationBuilder.build();
}
```

// METHOD for notifications when child is added

```
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


   // THIS METHODS ARE IN THE ONCREATE

    mListener = FirebaseUtils.getCHATSOLICITUDRef("8HaKY67AjaOD2a6QKrABhR2rcaJ3").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


             /// THE METHOD IS IN THIS
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, createNotification(
                    true));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `Services` so it will work at the background also check my code [here](https://gist.github.com/oussemaAr/6b27d4303d78b3562aac2f1f30ba4be9)

Comment: How do you implement it? I just create the class and put it in the manifest and that's it? and this shows when user is out the app? @Oussema Aroua

Comment: Yes just like that

Comment: <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.package.MyService" />

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: I wrote that code and works for me i hope it works for you, check it as sollution if it does

Comment: What's the problem

Comment: add `android:exported="true"` to the service tag